# laravel 4 - Sanitize Input::get() (e() vs HTML::entities in laravel 4)

Tags: php, laravel, xss, laravel-4, sanitization

I have read somewhere on the web that in the `blade` template engine, the `{{ }}` automatically sanitize output.

But, what if I want to `echo` a sanitized `Input::get` from the controller. What is the best way to do it (`e()` which is just an `htmlentities` or `HTML::entities` or something else)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I have read somewhere on the web that in the blade template engine, the {{ }} automatically sanitize output.

That is incorrect. You need to use three (3) curly braces to sanitize output `{{{ }}}`

> But, what if I want to echo a sanitized Input::get from the controller.

You should not output from your controllers - you should do it from a view

> What is the best way to do it (e() which is just an htmlentities or HTML::entities or something else)?

Yes - `e()` is the best way to do it in Laravel 4.

On the backend, all that `{{{ }}}` is doing is actually changing to the equilivant of `{{  e() }}` anyway

**Edit:** in Laravel 5 both `{{ }}` and `{{{ }}}` now sanitize output. If you need to have unsantized output in Laravel 5 - you can use `{!! !!}`

Comment: I have read it here : [Escaping output in laravel](http://www.arrowdesign.co.uk/blog-content/escaping-output-laravel)

Comment: It was that way for a brief time in the Laravel 4 beta - but it changed - so the blog is now out of date and wrong.

Comment: That is just stupid. For a framework like laravel, that shouldn't be the case. The default should be sanitized output and the unsanitized output be the triple braces. I just decided to test and realized that I would have shot myself in the foot.

Comment: @frostymarvelous this has changed in Laravel 5. In Laravel 5, the default `{{ }}` is santizied. The `{!! !!}` will be unsantisized

Comment: The fact that it was reverted in laravel 4 amazes me. I was just on the github thread. anyway, the rest of it is awesome so I guess I'll just have to find away to get around it.

Comment: Just add this to your `routes.php` or somewhere similar and change the L4 defaults to be the same as L5? No need to change any other code: `Blade::setEscapedContentTags('{{', '}}');` and   `Blade::setContentTags('{!!', '!!}');`